# Brouwer FPT:Given a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is continuous with bounded range, then there exists a fixed point $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing

There is a claim:

> Given a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is continuous with bounded range, then there exists a fixed point $x$.

I am not that familiar with Brouwer Fixed Point theorem, from Wikipedia there is a definition:

> Every continuous function from a closed ball of a Euclidean space into
>   itself has a fixed point.[7]

Well a closed ball in $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed interval $[a,b]$. We know that if $f$ has a bounded range then $|f(x)| \leq M, M \geq 0$.  How does bounded range help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x$, then $f$ maps $\mathbb{R}$ into $[-M,M]$, hence we can apply the Brouwer fixed point theorem to $f$ restricted to $[-M,M]$.

But rather than appeal to the full Brouwer fixed point theorem, we could just directly prove that $f$ has a fixed point: let $g(x)=f(x)-x$. Then $g(-M)=f(-M)+M\geq 0$ and $g(M)=f(M)-M\leq 0$.

If either $g(M)=0$ or $g(-M)=0$ then $f$ has a fixed point, so we are done. Otherwise $g(-M)>0$ and $g(M)<0$, so by the intermediate value theorem there is some $x_0\in (-M,M)$ such that $g(x_0)=0$, i.e. $f(x_0)=x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Any function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ has fixed points at exactly the points where it intersects the function $g(x) = x$.